# How to install a python on Symbian S60 3rd ed emulator?

Tags: emulation, symbian, s60, pys60, s60-3rd-edition

I can`t find any instruction how to install a pys60 2.0.0 to symbian emulator. All files I found [there](https://garage.maemo.org/frs/?group_id=854).

I unpacked SDK files to emulator directory and installed pips lib. When I install python sis file, emulator shows "Certificate error. Contact the application supplier."

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: My guess is you will never be able to make or fake a **v2** .SIS package installed into a **v3** Symbian S60v3. Used python on Nokia smartphone with GSM-network extensions. Cool days :o)

Comment: @user3666197, No, I have S60 3rd Ed FP1 emulator and use correct version of sis file. I also tried to install it 3rd Ed FP2 and 5th ed without success.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Btw, Artem, do you have any real-S60 device platform ( non-EMU'd ) with a live python interpreter working? Would like to re-run and cite pystone.py benchmark ( in [pystone/s] ) ( Nokia died too early to re-run on my own device ). Thx to let me know :o)

Comment: @user3666197, Yes I have. What this script doing and why you need this?

Comment: Cool, man! The **`pystone.py`** ( typically ver. 1.1 since py26, ver. 1.2 in recent py3+ ) is a standard python platform "benchmark", better to say a respective python interpreter-platform implementation's relative performance comparison test. It runs a series of incomplicated tests ( repeated ~ 50k times ) and measures time to run 'em, so that it allows to see, how efficiently the python version works on a common ground of this uniformed test. It may take ~ small hundreds seconds on S60-platform, so one ought be patient. Why? I collect performance data, yet Nokia 6670 died too early to log it

Comment: Would be glad to hear [pystones/s] and platform specification data, if you would not mind to re-run + log it for several times. Source is easy to copy, if not present in S60-device filesystem, but it is a std python component 
( **`>>> execfile( "test/pystone.py" ) # [ENTER]`** typically works as charm ) I copy/paste the complete test results + the whole python interpreter initial header text ( `Python2.6.8 [GCC 4.7.2] on ... execfile(...) ... Pystone(1.1) time for ... nnnnn.n pystones/second` ) and device/platform details to be able to find CPU/freq data. Appreciate your kind interest, Artem

Comment: Result on Nokia N95 8GB (Symbian 9.2, Python 2.5.4): `Pystone(1.1) time for 50000 passes = 29.1406
This machine benchmarks at 1715.82 pystones/second`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Artem, for your kind interest & help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to unpack OpenC SDK plugin files before python.